# How to submit an AJAX form with ENTER key, from textarea?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm developing a Ruby On Rails 2.3.8 application and I would like to know how to submit a `remote_form_for` form when users press the ENTER key within the textarea.

Here is the form code:

```
  <% remote_form_for :post, PostComment.new, :url => save_outside_comment_path(post_id), :html => { :method => :put} do |f| %>
     <%= f.text_area :comment, :rows => 1, :id => "txtOutsideComment_#{post_id}", :class => "new-reply-text" %>
  <% end %>
```

Here is the jQuery function that does a submit, but not AJAX:

```
jQuery('.new-reply-text').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.form.submit();
    }
});
```

I already do the page update from my controller, do I don't want to specify any syntax like `success:` from this jQuery function. I just want it to submit the `remote_form_for` using AJAX.

Answer (score 6):

I think you're asking how to do an AJAX request instead of a full page submit.  If so

```
jQuery('.new-reply-text').keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: "/my/URL",
      data: jQuery(this).form.serialize(),
      success: function(){},
      dataType: "json"
    });
  }
});
```

You can save a few parameters if you use .get
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

or .post
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Which are wrappers for .ajax
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

I'm not a rails guy so you'll need to update the class/id of the first jQuery object to find the `remote_form_for`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The issue of doing this is that I'm already doing the html replace from the controller's action, once the form is submitted. So, I don't want (or at least I have never done it this way) to specify a success event from jQuery, for example. Is there any other way in Rails for doing this?

Comment: just leave the success function empty

Comment: The idea behind the AJAX call is to process the submit request without reloading the entire page.  In this case you'd trigger the same controller action that handles the submit but instead it'd be called my the AJAX function.  You'd then send back down the HTML through the AJAX request and in the success function dynamically replace the contents of the form (or or area).