# unable to load data from server when submitting form using ajax jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I've a form as:

```
<form name="viewCustomerDetail" method="post">
    <label>View Account Detail</label>
    <ul>
        <li><input name="accountNumber" id="accountNumber" type="text" class="adminsearch"/></li>
        <li><input name="submit" id="submit" type="button" value="Get Customer"/></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

and the `script`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            var acc = $("#accountNumber").val();
            src = "pass.php";

            $.ajax({
                url: src,
                data: 'action=account&type=viewDetail&accNo='+acc,
                cache: false,
                type:'GET',
                success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
                    if(data!=0) {
                        $("#userInfo").html("");                        
                        $("#userInfo").css("display","block");
                        $("#userInfo").append(data);
                    }else{
                        $("#userInfo").html('');                        
                        $("#userInfo").append('<span class="alert-red alert-icon">Please Enter correct Account Number.</span>');
                        $("#userInfo").css("display","block");
                    }
                 },
             });
         });
     });
</script>
```

This `script` is working well when I click on the `button`, but if I change the `<input type="button"/>` to `<input type="submit"/>` it doesn't work. And also, I want to run the `script` when **ENTER** key is pressed in `<input type="text">`. Anybody could help, I'm newbie to `jQuery` and `ajax`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
$('#form_id').bind('submit',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //Will prevent the submit...
  //Add additional code here
});
```

Comment: should I replace `$("#submit").click(function()` with `$('#form_id').bind('submit',function(e)`

Comment: $('#target').submit(function() {
  alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
  return false;
});

Answer (score 1):

Try attaching your handler to form's [submit event](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) instead

Answer (score 1):

For the keypress (enter) there is already a thread which you can find here. I'm sure the answer fits your need: [How to submit an AJAX form with ENTER key, from textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358883/how-to-submit-an-ajax-form-with-enter-key-from-textarea)

Here the code:

```
jQuery('.new-reply-text').keypress(function(e) {
if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.form.submit();
}
});
```

For the click even use jQuerys .submit() function:

```
$("#submit").submit();
```

inside the submit you can pass another function with the ajax request inside.

Answer (score 1):

On using the `type="submit"` your form will go for the default action for which you have to use the prevent default method as specified above in one answer.

for attaching event to enter key press

```
$('#textbox').keypress(function(event){

var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
if(keycode == '13'){
//yourcode
}

});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

create a form id as viewCustomerDetail then

```
$("#accountNumber").keypress(function(event) {
 if ( event.which == 13 ) {
$("#viewCustomerDetail").submit();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply make a Submit function like `Submit()` and call it on Button click like:

```
input type="Button" value="Submit" onclick="Submit()"
```

Do not change its type to `submit.in submit()`, put code what you want to do on submit.